# Hide and show "other" option with checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I´m trying to make this code work but I don´t know how to do it... When I click on `Outro` the upper div closes, and when I click `Outra` **in the down one** the upper close.
I don´t know what I´m doing wrong because the function has different values and if it´s only one it works.
[image: https://imgur.com/a/khvjaAx]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-4" value="5">
        Outro
    </label>
<input type="text" maxlength="9" class="input-field4" id="input" name="teste">
</td>
</tr>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input').hide();
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
      console.log(e)
      if (e.target.id == "checkboxes-4" && e.target.checked) {
        $('#input').show();
      } else {
        $('#input').hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<tr>
  <th>Doenças</th>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-7">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-7" value="8">
            Outra
        </label>
  <input type="text" maxlength="9" class="input-field4" id="input1" name="teste1">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Contacto em caso de emergência</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="contacto_emergencia" value="<?php echo $contacto_emergencia;?>" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
<br>
<p align=right>
  <button type="submit" value="Alterar">Alterar</button>
  <button type="cancel" onclick="window.location='http://donutsrool.pt/ficha_aluno.php';return false;">Cancelar</button>
</p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input1').hide();
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
      console.log(e)
      if (e.target.id == "checkboxes-7" && e.target.checked) {
        $('#input1').show();
      } else {
        $('#input1').hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You have multiple listeners on the same element, it is better practise to set the listener on the element itself, could you try and make a jsFiddle to illustrate your problem?

Comment: I tryed too, but it does not work.. i have this online, i can give you a demo login..

Comment: Can you tell me more clear what you want? i don't get your expected point. i think your problem is you need different id and show hide based on id

Comment: Please explain in more in detail. what you want ?

Comment: Here your code is work perfectly. on click checkbox you get checkbox id and show / hide input (by id) according to get checkbox id.

Manage code as per your requirement.

Comment: Not working here... when I click on the first one it works good, but when I click on the second one, it open the second one but closes the first one..

Comment: Try to select both options